# Why firestore multiple whereEqualTo are not working

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
shiftId: {
    open: boolean,
    terminalId: string,
    startDate: Date
}
```

I've created an index like this:
[image: firestore index]

And my code query looks like this:

```
            shiftCollection
                .whereEqualTo("open", true)
                .whereEqualTo("terminal", "1")
                .orderBy("startDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(1)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (it.isEmpty){
                        Log.d(TAG, "There is no open shift")
                        return@addOnSuccessListener
                    }

                    .......
                }
```

And for sure I have at least one document matching filter criteria:
[image]

Yet query always return empty

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your entire database structure and please indicate how is `shiftCollection` initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying over `terminal` but the actual key in your db is `terminalId`